# Pause AWS S3 file upload

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload

I am developing a Springboot based POC to implement AWS S3 file upload/pause/resume functionality and following this https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html

In sample code under the description of `resumeUploadFile`, it mentions "// **Optionally**, persist the resumableFileUpload". Is this for recovering from scenarios like JVM crash? What's the impact if its not persisted?

Please advise.

Comment: Any exit scenario, JVM Crash, normal application exit, system reboot, etc.  Basically, scenarios where you want to resume the transfer from a new instance of the application.

Comment: @AnonCoward I've been following same document but unable to find a way to attach listener to the ```UploadFileRequest``` so that during any exception scenario ```resumableFileUpload``` information could be persisted. Can you please help with some pointers?